# Best UI layout for the scenario?

Tags: usability, layout, human-interface-guideline

[image][image]We have items and settings for them. All the settings done will affect the selected item(checkbox). Now what is the best way to show them on UI Layout. Splitting screen horizontally or vertically is a good practice?

**NOTE:** This screen is a modal window!!

Any suggestions are welcome..happy to provide more info if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the first one, horizontal split although this is an unusual layout settings. I would normally associate the left sidebar with navigation or filtering features. At first glance witout reading, I thought your left pane is used to filter the content on the right (Settings), probably due to my mental model of a side pane.

I have propose an alternate solution for your reference.

**Alternate Solutions**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnrmPt.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

User are more accustom to reading from top to bottom. The flow of information also makes a bit more sense here. Since its a modal window, screen estate is very crucial. By having the selection box inside settings, you need to scroll just one pane instead of two.

Comment: Thanks @adamsoh for your effort. But consider a huge list of items and a 10-15 settings. How do you manage scroll now? 1 scroll for items on top and 1 scroll for entire window? Correct me if am wrong. i will add image of what i understood out of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest it will be a multi selection drop down on the top of the settings, titled with ( please select items to apply settings to ) or something like that .

but it also depends on how many items in average you will select . and does the settings change based on selected items or not